# Android - SwipeRefreshLayout importing issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I am trying to implement the official Google Swiping Layout in my app but i cannot import. I checked every possible question here.

I did everything i was suppose to do:

1. i changed my manifest (target 19)
2. updated the Android SDK's support library (Android support 19.1)
3. i created a new project an copy the jar from the new project into my old project.

EDIT: i managed to import the library but now i am getting a crash when i start the activity that requires the SwipeRefreshLayout. Any opinions on that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: what's the error? post some code too.

Comment: Now it seems that i cannot import it at all. once again my problem is importing. The error: The import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout cannot be resolved

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but maybe you can try right clicking the android-support-v4.jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Answer (score 2):

So i managed to import the library: i created a new project and took the jar from the new project and import it via Configure Build Path (add jar).